# Add SharePoint Image public link in SSRS Report

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

While adding the public link of the SharePoint image in the SSRS Report, I am finding an issue with it. I cannot see the image showing in the SSRS Image.
[SharePoint Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjbRW.png)